# Javascript foreach with condition

Tags: javascript, performance, foreach

Here you can see my code :

```
this.tiles.forEach ( function($tile)
    {
            $tile.content.x = ( $tile.posY - $tile.posX ) * ($tile.map.tilesWidth/2) + ($tile.offsetX + $tile.map.offsetX);
            $tile.content.y = ( $tile.posY + $tile.posX ) * ($tile.map.tilesHeight/2) + ($tile.offsetY + $tile.map.offsetY);

            $tile.content.tile = $tile;
    });
```

So, for each tile in my array `tiles` i do some calculs.

Each item in my array have an attribut `posX` and `posY`.

My probleme here it's if i have a lots of tiles in my array, this foreach take a long time to execute.

I need to add a condition and do this stuff for each tile where posX is between Xmin and Xmax, same thing for posY.

How can i do that as simply as possible? To save the greatest possible resource.. thanks !

Add a if condition in my array is not a good solution cause the foreach will still go through the whole array..

Comment: `forEach` goes through the entire array, no matter what. Try adding an `if` expression around the 3 lines of code inside that function that checks for your desired range in `$tile.posX`

Comment: Can you give an example of your array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
this.tiles
    .filter ( function($tile)
    {
            return $tile.posX <= Xmin && $tile.posX >= Xmax && 
                   $tile.posY <= Ymin && $tile.posY >= Ymax;
    })
    .forEach ( function($tile)
    {
            $tile.content.x = ( $tile.posY - $tile.posX ) * ($tile.map.tilesWidth/2) + ($tile.offsetX + $tile.map.offsetX);
            $tile.content.y = ( $tile.posY + $tile.posX ) * ($tile.map.tilesHeight/2) + ($tile.offsetY + $tile.map.offsetY);

            $tile.content.tile = $tile;
    });
```

But a simple `for`-loop would be more efficient:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.tiles.length; i++)
{
    var $tile = this.tiles[i];
    if ($tile.posX <= Xmin && $tile.posX >= Xmax && 
        $tile.posY <= Ymin && $tile.posY >= Ymax)
    {
        $tile.content.x = ( $tile.posY - $tile.posX ) * ($tile.map.tilesWidth/2) + ($tile.offsetX + $tile.map.offsetX);
        $tile.content.y = ( $tile.posY + $tile.posX ) * ($tile.map.tilesHeight/2) + ($tile.offsetY + $tile.map.offsetY);

        $tile.content.tile = $tile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for .filter. But you think the for loop is more efficient ?

Comment: @ClémentAndraud `for` loops are generally more efficient because calling a function is expensive

Comment: Can you demonstrate the improved efficiency of the `for` loop as opposed to the `filter().forEach()` array-methods, wiht a [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/), maybe?

Comment: @ClémentAndraud `.filter` loops through every item in `tiles` and constructs a new array, then `.forEach` loops through every item in the result array. Using a simple for-loop saves you from having to construct the new array or unnecessary function calls.